# Case-sensitive match in TEXTJOIN and COUNTIF Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I apply "case-sensitive" match in this COUNTIF (case-insensitive) formula in Microsoft Excel 2019?

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(COUNTIF(A2; "*"&$D$2:$D$1400&"*"); $D$2:$D$1400; ""))
```

This formula (written in cell B2) checks if A2 contains a value of D2:D1400 and shows it in a comma separated list.

Actual matching is case-insensitive, but I want to use case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use `FIND()` since it's case-sensitive:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,D2:D1400)),D2:D1400,""))
```

Or, the reversed:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(D2:D1400,A1)),D2:D1400,""))
```